# La différence entre « Je ne trouve pas mes lunettes. » et « Je ne retrouve pas mes lunettes. »

Tags: usage, verbes, préfixes

Je m'interroge sur la différence entre :

> Je ne **trouve** pas mes lunettes.
>
> et : Je ne **retrouve** pas mes lunettes.

Est-ce qu'on utilise le premier quand on les a égarées chez soi, alors que le second est plutôt pour quand on l'a fait dans un grand espace, par exemple dans un aéroport, ou pendant qu'on se promène ?

Comment: Il y a de nombreuses nuances en fonction du contexte. Dans votre exemple, je pense que retrouver est plus approprié, même si "trouvé" est souvent rencontré aussi et ne me paraît pas totalement incongru. Pour les nuances, je vous renvoie vers http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/trouver et http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/trouver, je pourrais difficilement faire une réponse aussi exhaustive...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Il n'y a aucune différence, et ce quel que soit le lieu où on les a perdues, entre :

> Je ne trouve pas mes lunettes.

et

> Je ne retrouve pas mes lunettes.

Bien que dans cette phrase les deux verbes aient le même sens je pense qu'il est plus fréquent d'employer « retrouver » parce qu'on connaît l'objet et qu'on le cherche.

Si j'ai perdu mes lunettes et que c'est ma mère qui les trouve dans la salle de bains alors qu'elle ne savait pas que je les avais perdues elle va dire :

> J'ai trouvé tes lunettes dans la salle de bains.

(et pas retrouvé).

On emploie « trouver » pour quelque chose qu'on n'a jamais vu auparavant et qu'on trouve accidentellement (un portefeuille dans la rue) ou volontairement (la définition d'un mot dans le dictionnaire, de l'or dans un cours d'eau...).

Un bon article sur les emplois de « trouver » et « retrouver » [sur la BDL](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=4246)

Le préfixe -re a beaucoup de sens et est parfois difficile à employer pour les non francophones.
Un article relativement simple sur le préfixe re :
[L'usage du préfixe « Re » en français](http://www.hommes-et-faits.com/Linguistique/Jh_PrefixeRe.htm)
et un article de recherche :
[Re- dans tous ses états, un « préfixe » marquant l’aspect implicatif](http://linx.revues.org/705#tocto1n4)

Comment: Et que dire de *j'ai reperdu mes lunettes* ? :p

Comment: @SimonDéchamps Si je reperds mes lunettes j'espère les retrouver ...  ça ne changera rien à l'emploi de trouver/retrouver. Perdre et reperdre n'ont pas des emplois parallèles à ceux de trouver/retrouver.

Answer (score 0):

On peut en effet faire une distinction entre les deux, mais plutôt dans un sens temporel que spatial: la première correspondrait au verbe "chercher", et la seconde "rechercher". Dans cette seconde, on peut avoir l'impression  que la "recherche" a duré plus longtemps.

Notez que l'on peut dire

> Je ne trouve pas mes lunettes.

dans un contexte où vous êtes en train de choisir une paire dans un magasin, mais que vous ne trouvez pas le modèle qui vous plait (alors que vous ne les possédez ^pas encore).

Answer (score 0):

Notons que si on parle de la foi (ou d'un autre autre sentiment) :

> J'ai trouvé la foi.

... signifie qu'on ne l'avait pas avant, alors que :

> J'ai retrouvé la foi.

... signifie qu'on l'avait déjà trouvée, puis perdue, et désormais retrouvée.

Alors que dans le cas des lunettes, *retrouver* ne signifie pas qu'on les avait déjà trouvées avant de les perdre.

Mindfuck.